# Jquery click on span or <i>?

Tags: jquery

I have a span containing a font-awesome icon, and I'm trying to get jquery to detect clicks on it, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is it possible?

```
<span style='margin-right: 20px;'><i name='remove' value='" + groupList[i] + "' class='fa fa-times-circle-o' style='color: #337ab7;'> </i> " + groupList[i] + "</span>

$("[name=remove]").click(function() {
  alert($(this).value());
});
```

Comment: Try `$("[name='remove']")`

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Just for clarity, I don't want to detect clicks on the text that comes after the fa icon, only when the icon itself is clicked.

Comment: if this is the only context you're using `fa-times-circle-o` you could use: `$('i.fa-times-circle-o')`, otherwise i'd suggest adding a unique class or id to the `i` element.

Comment: "if this is the only context you're using fa-times-circle-o you could use: $('i.fa-times-circle-o'), otherwise i'd suggest adding a unique class or id to the i element."

I tried that but still no go. It should be working, but it's not. I also tried adding an <a> tag around it. but no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your click handler works, but `value()` isn't a function. You should call `$.val()` or `value` instead. It won't return anything, since the `i` tag doesn't have a `value` but the click handler will fire an `alert()` window, and getting the selector firing is your goal.

```js
$("[name=remove]").click(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span style='margin-right: 20px;'><i name='remove' value='" + groupList[i] + "' class='fa fa-times-circle-o' style='color: #337ab7;'> </i> " + groupList[i] + "</span>
```

I'm guessing the thing you want to alert is this instead

```
alert($(this).parent().text());
```

```js
$("[name=remove]").click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span style='margin-right: 20px;'><i name='remove' value='" + groupList[i] + "' class='fa fa-times-circle-o' style='color: #337ab7;'> </i> " + groupList[i] + "</span>
```

Also, if this content is rendered client-side, you need to use `$(document).on('click', "[name=remove]", function() {...})` instead of `$("[name=remove]").click(function() {...})`

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. Without even trying to pull any data value from the <i> tag, I just did a basic alert, alert("Good") and it never fired. It seems like the click isn't being detected at all on the <i> tag. I also tried moving it to the <span> tag and no go.

Comment: @MattMorrow I updated my answer with a working code example using the selector you have that is working. Your click handler is just fine - it's just the thing you're trying to alert that isn't working.

Comment: Michael Coker: I am doing exactly that, and it just won't fire. Could it be that this is a partial html that I am pulling from an external file and appending to an already existing page? This content gets dropped into a div lower in the main page using  a server-side script.

Though, the other jquery and ajax calls on this same file work fine.

Comment: @MattMorrow if you're including this content as a partial server-side and the content is actually on the page (versus being rendered by JS/client-side), then what you have should work. If you're loading the partial dynamically via JS, it could be that you're using `$.click()` instead of `$.on()`. Try changing the click handler to `$(document).on('click', "[name=remove]", function() {` btw did you downvote my answer? as far as I know, nothing I've said or showed is wrong.

Comment: Michael Coker: I don't think I downvoted it - if I did it was accidental, I'm not even sure how to up or downvote, I've never seen a button or link to do that.

Comment: I found the upvote, and clicked it for your response. But, your last suggestion worked great, for $(document).on('click',...)

Thanks a ton, this will get me moving forward.

Comment: @MattMorrow sweet! Yeah you need to use `$(document).on('click',...)` on elements rendered client-side. `$.click()` usually only works for elements that were already in the HTML and not added client-side.

Comment: @MattMorrow I'll also update my answer with that info if that solved your issues.